# update column in the same row using ID,sqlite

Tags: objective-c, database, sqlite

I have 5 columns in my table in which 3 values are coming from one save method and 2 are coming from another.When i insert the data from first save method first 3 columns get filled and now I want other 2 columns to be get filled by next update method but in same row.
I tried to update using ID but this is updating in particular row only.
P.S:-I am newbie to iOS & first time working on sqlite.
 here what I did  :-

```
-(BOOL)createDB
{
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = dirPaths[0];
    // Build the path to the database file
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:
                    [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Calendardatabase.db"]];

    NSLog(@"%@",databasePath);
    BOOL isSuccess = YES;
    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            char *errMsg;
            const char *sql_stmt =

"create table if not exists CalendarDataTable (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,pl1 text, recordedTmpFile text,NavlabelDate text,eventTypeImgView text,eventNameLblP2 text)";
            if (sqlite3_exec(database, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg)
                != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                isSuccess = NO;
                NSLog(@"Failed to create table");
            }
            sqlite3_close(database);
            return  isSuccess;
        }
        else {
            isSuccess = NO;
            NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
        }
    }
    return isSuccess;
}


-(BOOL)saveData:(NSString*)pl1 recordedTmpFile:(NSString*)recordedTmpFile NavlabelDate:(NSString*)NavlabelDate eventTypeImgView:(NSString*)eventTypeImgView eventNameLblP2:(NSString*)eventNameLblP2;
//-(BOOL)saveData:(NSString*)eventTypeImgView eventNameLblP2:(NSString*)eventNameLblP2 pl1:(NSString*)pl1 pl2:(NSString*)pl2 pl3:(NSString*)pl3 pl4:(NSString*)pl4;
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into CalendarDataTable (pl1,recordedTmpFile,NavlabelDate,eventTypeImgView,eventNameLblP2) values (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",pl1,recordedTmpFile,NavlabelDate,eventTypeImgView,eventNameLblP2];


        //   NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into CalendarDataTable (eventTypeImgView, eventNameLblP2 pl1 pl2 pl3 pl4) values (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",eventTypeImgView,eventNameLblP2,pl1,pl2,pl3,pl4];


        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            return NO;
        }
     //   sqlite3_reset(statement);
    }
    return NO;
}


-(BOOL)UpdateTable:(NSString*)eventTypeImgView eventNameLblP2:(NSString*)eventNameLblP2;
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE  CalendarDataTable set eventTypeImgView='%@',eventNameLblP2='%@' where ID=1",eventTypeImgView,eventNameLblP2];
        NSLog(@"%@",updateSQL);
        const char *insert_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            return NO;
        }
      //  sqlite3_reset(statement);
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is to identify in `UpdateTable...` the row saved in `saveData...` method, you can use custom identifier, generated in some way from the data inserted in `saveData...`.

Let's say add an extra field to `CalendarDataTable` called `created` and store some unique generated value in it, for example current timestamp `[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] * 1000`, store timestamps and use them is `where` clause insted of `ID`

Comment: thanks for the answer.do you know how to generate unique ID  on the cell click,aince I have 2 tableview on the same VC.

Comment: @iOSBeginner if this answer solved the problem mark it as accepted (checkmark on the left side). Question about generating on cell click is a different question, create separate topic if you won't find solution by yourself. BTW I personally use https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb for SQLite, it is a good wrapper around all the sqlite3 stuff you use here

Comment: I want key Unique everytime,since you are showing to use date It'll differ from day to day

Comment: @iOSBeginner Ok and what is the problem?

Comment: I want anything unique which will generate when I click on the button on cell so that by using that ID I can update my table

Comment: Then use [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] * 1000, you will get a unique time stamp